# Can I color my turtle?

Tags: java, class, colors

**edit: when writing w. a list pops up of  the methods avaible to simplewindow. One of them is**

> setLineColor(Color arg0): void - SimpleWindow

**Now if I doubble click on this line in the popup window, I get the code** `w.setLineColor(arg0);` **printed.. Where do I go from here? I have no clue.**

Hello I had this school asignment to make 2 turtles walk around in a box until they get 50px or closer to eachother, which I did. However just for fun I would like to color them if thats possible. I google searched for it and found a color class which I think I managed to import. Iam not sure how classes or almost anything works so I have no idea really what Iam doing.

The class I imported was `import java.awt.*;`

This is what my turtle program looks like when I run it https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMU7I.png and here under is the code(you wont be able to run it since I have classes from school you dont have I think) note that ive put color code randomly, i tried to color smth..

```
    package ovn4;

import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;

import se.lth.cs.window.SimpleWindow;
import se.lth.cs.p.ovn.turtle.Turtle;

public class g455 {
    public void getRed() {

    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        SimpleWindow w = new SimpleWindow(500,500,"squratle window");
        Turtle t1 = new Turtle(w,222,222);
        Turtle t2 = new Turtle(w,100,400);
        Color c= new Color(100);
        c.getRed();


        int y1 = 5;
        int x1=5;
        int y2=5;
        int x2=5;


        int z = 100;

        while(z>49) {

            SimpleWindow.delay(1);
            Random rand = new Random();
            int steps = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
            int vinkel = rand.nextInt(359)-179;
            t1.penDown();
            t1.forward(steps);
            t1.right(vinkel);
            x1=t1.getX();
            y1=t1.getY();

            rand = new Random();
            steps = rand.nextInt(10)+1;
            vinkel=rand.nextInt(359)-179;
            t2.penDown();
            t2.forward(steps);
            t2.right(vinkel);

            y2=t2.getY();
            x2=t2.getX();

            z= (x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2);
            z= (int) Math.sqrt(z);  

        }
        System.out.println("avståndet mellan dom är "+z+" pixlar.");

    }

    }
```

So one of the turtles are called t1. Now I would like to color his footsteps so to speak to red instead of the default black, could anyone help me with this?

Comment: To answer that, we'll have to know the particular library you're using. Chances are you won't find anyone here that does.

Comment: Seems it would be in your `penDown` function. Do you have the source for that?

Comment: Show us the code of Turtle class

Comment: Must dig into the javadoc or even the source files of Turtle Graphics. The `SimpleWindow` or a subcomponent may do the drawing, and perhaps that implies a `NotassimpleWindow` that could give you more control.

Comment: How do I do any of this? Where and what is my library? How do I show the code of the Turtle class? I dont know anything of what you 4 people just said :(..

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the library, it's just a bit of a shot in the dark, but the old turtle graphics API's used to use the command `setPenColor(color)` for it, so it's worth a shot trying to perform a `t1.setPenColor(c);`

Cheers and good luck in your learning.

Edit: Your newly found setLineColor() method takes in a Color, as indicated in the method signature. Just pass it in a color - I'd recommend getting rid of your 'getRed()' method, it's not doing anything for you. Try this:

```
Color red = new Color(100);
w.setLineColor(red);
```

What's happening here is that you're defining a new color, and calling it 'red', and passing in a value(100) into the color constructor. That color constructor understands that 100 is somewhere in the red family of colors. Then, you're telling your window to set its line color to that color.

Comment: I get the message The method setPenColor(Color) is undefined for the type Turtle.. Are methods what a class contains? So if my turtle class does not contain a color method, i cant color my turtle even if i import the color class?.. I dont understand how everything hangs together :(..

Comment: @user2779497 as Nick said, his answer was a shot in the dark, because we have no idea what libraries you're using.  Please update your question with that information and then we might have a chance of helping you.

Comment: Iam not sure what libraries are. Where can I find them? I can upload my workspace which contains the tools to run my turtle program if thats what you mean?

Comment: @user2779497 Methods are one of the things that classes contain, they're sections of code that are used to get things done. For example, your Turtle class has a 'forward' method, that makes it move forward. I would guess that it's likely that it has a method that will set its color as well, but without being able to see the code or documentation for it, all we can do is guess what it might be. See if you can find the documentation for the Turtle class that lists the methods it contains.

Comment: Well i have a bit of documantation on a piece of paper here that has a few methods including the void forward(int n); that you described. But it says nothing about colors. So if I dont have this information I cant paint my turtles track? Is there any place in some folder methods are normally found? Like I know that I import my turtle from import se.lth.cs.p.ovn.turtle.Turtle;. Can I use this information to get info about methods?

Comment: @user2779497 Well, we're really getting beyond the scope of the question, but you can potentially use reflection to get the method names available in the turtle class... Class turtleClass = t1.GetClass(); Method[] methods = turtleClass.GetMethods(); for (Method method : methods) { System.out.println(method.toString()); } should output a list of the methods available. Run that, see what comes out, see if that list mentions anything about colors. Report back and good luck!

Comment: I changed Get to get so
`Class turtleClass = t1.getClass();`gives a yellow but not a red error.
`Method[] methods = turtleClass.getMethods();` gives error "Method cannot be resolved to a type"

edit i clicked on my red error and it said smth with "import blabla" so i pressed that and the error dissapeared. I run the code/program and it gave me as you said alot of methods(is it called methods?)
example public `void se.lth.cs.p.ovn.turtle.Turtle.forward(int)`. However it said nothing about colors.

Comment: So these methods that popped up, is this what a guy has written or is this some kind of automatic thing thats gets made? Because if its a guy that writes all this, he could have just not written the color method even though it's there right?

Answer (score 1):

**edit: when writing w. a list pops up of  the methods avaible to simplewindow. One of them is**

> setLineColor(Color arg0): void - SimpleWindow

**Now if I doubble click on this line in the popup window, I get the code** `w.setLineColor(arg0);` **printed.. Where do I go from here? I have no clue.**